# Open new powershell console and run a command

Tags: powershell, command-line

I would like to add a line to my script that open a new power shell console and run a ping command in the new window.

Comment: Tell us what you have tried

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
start-process powershell.exe -argument '-nologo -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -command Test-Connection ipAddressToPing; read-host "press enter"'
```

You can add the ip address to the script or leave it out and it will ask you for it at runtime.  You can remove the read-host "press enter"' if you want the window to close right away.

Comment: Thank you.I will try it and let u know. is there a way to after the ping will return an answer that it will try to connect to my server Until he succeeds. and when it succeed then it will open the Vsphere client?

Comment: Hi, i'v tried it and it work. i have one more question. after i will get a reply from the server can it open the vsphere client automatically with the details?